# How to select data randomly in 2-d array

Tags: arrays, c++11, random

I want to get some data randomly from an 2-d array.

In my partial code given below where cluster_center and sample data both are 2-d array in double type. I want to assign some data randomly from sample_data array to cluster_center array.

```
for(int i= 0; i< 3; i++)
{
    for(k=0; k<17; k++)
        cluster_center[i][k] = //what will be???;
}
```

TIA :)

Comment: Do you want to get a random data from sample data array?

Comment: Any reason you tag for two different languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a random C++ program generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154484/is-there-a-random-c-program-generator)

Comment: There is also the question of whether you want to use any of the data samples *more than once*. Or if data can move to another row (there must be a reason for a 2-d array). There are different answers accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I have done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just generate two random numbers via [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) and `modulate` it to ensure it doesn't exceed your 2-D array boundaries. Not sure exactly how random you need it to be though, as `rand` will favor lower numbers slightly according to the man page.

You'd assign the value like:

```
cluster_center[i][k] = sample_data[random_num1][random_num2];
```